# Maple evalution rules at function definition

Tags: maple

I am trying to define a function, A, which has a function call, B, in its body. The function call to B is independent of input parameters of A. Maple does not call B at function definition. Is there any way to force it to evaluate call to B at function definition time?
Example:

```
B := x -> 2 * x;
A := x -> B(2) + x ^ 2;
```

A first it might look irelevent to ask for compution a constant at function definition type, but it have some usage cases for example at higher order functions:

```
A := n -> (x-> add(i, i=1..n)*x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A:= subs(Z = B(2), (x -> Z + x^2));
```

Answer (score 0):

While Roberts answer is good and general purpose, I'd mention that for simple 1-line procedure `B` there is another way which accomplishes the goal automatically.

It involves having `option inline` on `B`.

For example,

```
restart;

B := proc(x) option inline; 2 * x; end proc:

A := x -> B(2) + x ^ 2;

                       2
        A := x -> 4 + x
```

Or, if you want the body of `B` to still print with the arrow (though hiding its `inline` nature from overt view),

```
restart;

B := proc(x) option inline, operator, arrow; 2 * x; end proc;

        B := x -> 2 x

A := x -> B(2) + x ^ 2;

                       2
        A := x -> 4 + x
```

Comment: As I understood by specifying `iniline` option we tell Maple to treat `B` as arithmetic operators which it replace them with their results during function defention procces. Did I got it right?

Comment: There is no restriction of B to "arithmetic" operations. But, yes, the `inline` option on procedure B causes the call to B inside another procedure's definition to be replaced by the "results".